# HBase displays timestamp value properly?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

If HBase is storing timestamp of each column in long, how it displays values in proper numeric format when accessed from hbase shell on terminal, if I store other values in long it displays in following fashion not readable `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0By\x80` directly unless you convert in java code. Or does HBase have other datatype to store timestamp values?

```
 APP:APP_ID                                 timestamp=1337657056164, value=\x00\x00\x00$
 APP:APP_NAME                               timestamp=1337657056164, value=java.process
 TUW:EXCEPTION                              timestamp=1337657056164, value=0
 TUW:TUW_ID                                 timestamp=1337657056164, value=\x00\x00\x12\x08
 TUW:TUW_STATUS                             timestamp=1337657056164, value=\x00\x00\x00\x02
```

Answer (score 4):

Any value you store in HBase looks something like `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0By\x80`, because HBase treats every value as a byte array, irrespective of its datatype. That's why you have to convert these values back into java types in order see them.

While the timestamp is something used by Hbase internally for versioning the stored data and it is "the time in seconds since the epoch". It can also be some other value of our choice. We can specify the timestamp while inserting the data.

Comment: @Tariq-Yes I'm aware that everything hbase stores is in form of bytes but when you could see timestamp in numeric formatt why other data entered by you is not shown in similar fashion.

Comment: @shahsanket - because the timestamp is a known and integral part of the key, the value on the otherhand could be anything (as Tariq says)

Comment: @Chris -Let data be anything as long as its LONG then it should show up, the same way as timestamp is getting shown, but that's not happening.

Comment: your data is something that is inserted by you, while timestamp is something that is managed by the Hbase itself and not the user..and since it is internal to the Hbase, it is fully aware of the type and format of the timestamp..on the other hand user data could be anything, from string to integer to char to float, and so on..so Hbase adapts a unified approach for handling any kind of data, by converting data of any kind into a byte array..don't think of timestamp as a part of your data..it is rather a part of the triplet that is used to identify the data stored in a particular Hbase cell.

Comment: _"the time in seconds since the epoch"_ I think you meant milliseconds.